# Callback URI not working after successful login

Tags: reactjs, react-native, spotify

I am using a React Native npm package for the Spotify SDK ( https://github.com/lufinkey/react-native-spotify ). The app progresses through the login page and privacy agreement policy pages just fine, after clicking accept, the app "thinks" for a second and then returns back to the original "Log in With Spotify Page" instead of progressing to my Video page.

[image]

My thought is that my callback url is not set up correctly through Spotify? Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    ActivityIndicator,
    Alert,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TouchableHighlight,
    View
} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import Spotify from 'rn-spotify-sdk';

class SpotifyLogin extends Component
{
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    };

    constructor()
    {
        super();

        this.state = {spotifyInitialized: false};
        this.spotifyLoginButtonWasPressed = this.spotifyLoginButtonWasPressed.bind(this);
    }

    goToPlayer()
    {
        const navAction = NavigationActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [
              NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Video'})
            ]
        });
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(navAction);
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        // initialize Spotify if it hasn't been initialized yet
        if(!Spotify.isInitialized())
        {
            // initialize spotify
            var spotifyOptions = {
                "clientID":"0adddabe05f64f499e3778f300d77d51",
                "sessionUserDefaultsKey":"SpotifySession",
                "redirectURL":"uncvrdapp://auth",
                "scopes":["user-read-private", "playlist-read", "playlist-read-private", "streaming"],
            };
            Spotify.initialize(spotifyOptions).then((loggedIn) => {
                // update UI state

                this.setState({spotifyInitialized: true});
                // handle initialization
                if(loggedIn)
                {
                    this.goToPlayer();
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                Alert.alert("Error", error.message);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // update UI state
            this.setState((state) => {
                state.spotifyInitialized = true;
                return state;
            });
            // handle logged in
            if(Spotify.isLoggedIn())
            {
                this.goToPlayer();
            }
        }
    }

    spotifyLoginButtonWasPressed()
    {
        // log into Spotify
        Spotify.login().then((loggedIn) => {
            if(loggedIn)
            {
                // logged in
                this.goToPlayer();
            }
            else
            {
                // cancelled
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            // error
            Alert.alert("Error", error.message);
        });
    }

    render()
    {
        if(!this.state.spotifyInitialized)
        {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <ActivityIndicator animating={true} style={styles.loadIndicator}>
                    </ActivityIndicator>
                    <Text style={styles.loadMessage}>
                        Loading...
                    </Text>
                </View>
            );
        }
        else
        {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.greeting}>
                        Hey! You! Log into your spotify
                    </Text>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.spotifyLoginButtonWasPressed} style={styles.spotifyLoginButton}>
                        <Text style={styles.spotifyLoginButtonText}>Log into Spotify</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default SpotifyLogin;
```

Next is my Spotify Developer console to show my callback URI.

[image]

They are the same. Where am I going wrong and why does it not progress to the video page like I am expecting it to? Thank you!

Comment: Is there any error you get?

Comment: Can you please console.log "loggedIn" in componentDidMount() if() statement and "Spotify.isLoggedIn()" in else() statement.

Comment: @HungrySoul I just tried console.logging and reading output in chrome but I received this error:

Invariant Violation: Calling synchronous methods on native modules is not supported in Chrome. Consider providing alternative methods to expose this method in debug mode, e.g. by exposing constants ahead-of-time.

Comment: @PritishVaidya I can't seem to debug using console.log in chrome, see the above response...hmm

Comment: Can you once try replacing "this.goToPlayer()" with console statements on both the if else statements. And are you sure you are not getting a red screen with the same error on your device?

Comment: @HungrySoul okay so I commented out the `goToPlayer()` in both if and else statements in the `componentDidMount()` and replaced with a console.log(loggedIn). Still same error, and yes, the same error is reflected between browser and red screen error on my simulated device :)

Comment: @HungrySoul just tried using `alert(loggedIn)` so I wouldnt have to use chrome tools and alerts didn't even pop up on my screen for either case

Comment: Do you mind if i use the above code to reproduce the issue from my computer>

Comment: @HungrySoul not at all, feel free to use. If you need anything else please let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169154/discussion-between-hungrysoul-and-jordan-lewallen).

Comment: @HungrySoul please let me know when you are available again. I had to get some sleep, sorry I missed your message

Comment: @JordanLewallen please click on the link stating "continue this discussion in chat".

Comment: @HungrySoul just entered chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the chat. The issue can be solved by converting them into async methods.

```
componentDidMount()
    {
        // initialize Spotify if it hasn't been initialized yet
        if(!Spotify.isInitializedAsync())
        {
            // initialize spotify
            var spotifyOptions = {
                "clientID":"0adddabe05f64f499e3778f300d77d51",
                "sessionUserDefaultsKey":"SpotifySession",
                "redirectURL":"uncvrdapp://auth",
                "scopes":["user-read-private", "playlist-read", "playlist-read-private", "streaming"],
            };
            Spotify.initialize(spotifyOptions).then((loggedIn) => {
                // update UI state

                this.setState({spotifyInitialized: true});
                // handle initialization
                if(loggedIn)
                {
                    this.goToPlayer();
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                Alert.alert("Error", error.message);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // update UI state
            this.setState((state) => {
                state.spotifyInitialized = true;
                return state;
            });
            // handle logged in
            if(Spotify.isLoggedInAsync()) // <-- here
            {
                this.goToPlayer();
            }
        }
    }

    spotifyLoginButtonWasPressed()
    {
        // log into Spotify
        Spotify.login().then((loggedIn) => {
            if(loggedIn)
            {
                // logged in
                this.goToPlayer();
            }
            else
            {
                // cancelled
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            // error
            Alert.alert("Error", error.message);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hey, sorry late response, but I'm the developer of this package. Calling isLoggedInAsync without awaiting the result promise will always evaluate to `true`, because the result is a promise and not a boolean. You should `await` the result of `isLoggedInAsync`